# How can I run this stored procedure with options?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE Docente
(
    opcion varchar2(10),
    id_Docente NUMBER,
    nombre VARCHAR2(30),
    apellido VARCHAR2(30),
    cedula NUMBER,
    titulo VARCHAR2(100),
    observaciones VARCHAR2(200),
    estado VARCHAR2(10),
    mensaje varchar2(50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Docente PRIMARY KEY (id_Docente)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_crud_docente(
p_opcion    varchar2,
p_id_Docente NUMBER,
p_nombre VARCHAR2,
p_apellido VARCHAR2,
p_cedula NUMBER,
p_titulo VARCHAR2,
p_observaciones VARCHAR2,
p_estado VARCHAR2,
p_mensaje out varchar2) 
as
v_valor int;
v_row Docente%rowtype;
    begin  
        if (p_opcion = 'I') then             
              begin
             Select  MAX(id_Docente)+ 1  into v_valor from Docente;
            if v_valor is null then 
            v_valor := 1;
              p_mensaje:= 'Registro inserted...';  
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_mensaje);   
            insert into Docente
            values (p_opcion,v_valor,p_id_Docente,p_nombre,p_apellido,p_cedula,p_titulo,p_observaciones,p_estado);
        end if;
        end;

          else if (p_opcion = 'U') then 
          
            update Docente set  opcion=p_opcion,
                                id_Docente=p_id_Docente,
                                nombre=p_nombre,
                                apellido=p_apellido,
                                cedula=p_cedula,
                                titulo=p_titulo,
                                observaciones=p_observaciones,
                                estado=p_estado
                           where id_Docente=p_id_Docente;
             p_mensaje:= 'Registro updated...';   
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_mensaje);
          else if (p_opcion = 'S') then   
           begin
            Select 
            opcion,
            id_Docente,
            nombre,
            apellido,
            cedula,
            titulo,
            observaciones,
            estado, 
            mensaje
            into v_row 
            from Docente;
        p_mensaje := ('Ok');
                      
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_mensaje||' --> '||v_row.opcion||'|'||v_row.id_Docente||'|'||v_row.nombre||'|'||v_row.apellido||'|'||v_row.cedula||'|'||v_row.titulo||'|'||v_row.observaciones||'|'||v_row.estado||'|'||v_row.mensaje);
         end;
               
             else if (p_opcion = 'D') then  
              
                Delete from Docente where id_Docente=p_id_Docente;
                
                    p_mensaje := ('Proceso ejecutado correctamente');
                    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_mensaje);
    commit;
            
          end if;
           end if;
           end if;  
            end if;  
         
         EXCEPTION  
           WHEN OTHERS then 
           p_mensaje := ('ERROR. No se pudo ejecutar el proceso');
           rollback;
          end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the length of the incoming parameters:

```
create or replace procedure sp_crud_docente (
p_opcion    varchar2,
p_id_Docente NUMBER,
p_nombre VARCHAR2,
p_apellido VARCHAR2,
p_cedula NUMBER,
p_titulo VARCHAR2,
p_observaciones VARCHAR2,
p_estado VARCHAR2,
p_mensaje out varchar2)
```

See 8.7.1 Formal and Actual Subprogram Parameters section of the 19c manual "Database PL/SQL Language Reference"

Bobby

Comment: I already tried that but there I get the following:  Errors: PROCEDURE SP_CRUD_DOCENTE
Line/Col: 22/4 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 22/16 PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
Line/Col: 39/13 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 47/24 PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
Line/Col: 48/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Line/Col: 48/43 PLS-00302: component 'OPCION' must be declared

Comment: Maybe you should restate your question with these errors and include the definition (CREATE TABLE statement) for the table. Also, if you can get the output from sqlplus with the line numbers it makes it easier to see which line corresponds to the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `varchar2` parameters can't have size, this is practically unsolvable without you posting the `docente` table description.

Bad habits kick; you're wrongly relying on the fact that you know what you're doing, but it turns out you don't.

I can't figure out how many nor which columns `docente` contains, and in which order.

`insert into docente` should explicitly mention all columns you're inserting into, one-by-one. Code you wrote suggests that table contains **9** columns `(opcion, id_docente, nombre, apellido, cedula, titulo, observaciones, estado)`.

`update`, on the other hand, updates only **6** of them `(nombre, apellido, cedula, tutlo, observaciones, estado)` which doesn't collide with `insert`; it is OK if you don't update all columns.

However, `p_opcion = 'S'` selects only **7** columns into `v_row` which is declared as `docente%rowtype`. Out of those 7 columns, I believe you "forgot" a comma between `id_docente` and `nombre` - those are two columns, it's not that `nombre` is `id_docente`'s alias, right? Suppose it is **8** columns that are selected after all. Now, that **collides** with number of columns you used in `insert` (9 of them). If you're selecting into `%rowtype`, you must select ALL columns in EXACT ORDER.

I suggest you review code you wrote, pay attention about what I said and fix those errors.